# Teams Bot suddenly “404 not found”

Tags: azure, http-status-code-404, microsoft-teams, ngrok

I’ve been running a MS Teams bot without issues for about half a year now. It is written in Python, using the bot builder SDK, and connected to Teams/Azure via ngrok. Users use it by clicking on the link, which opens up the chatbot in their Teams app (desktop or mobile).

Out of a sudden, some time on 3rd Feb 2023, the bot started having issues sending replies out. And reports a “404 not found error” in ngrok. There’s been no changes to the chatbot’s code.

To be clear, the bot is able to receive the user inputs, but fails to send the replies out.

Would anyone know why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer. The app secret value expired and simply needs to be renewed. I had suppressed the trackbacks, not expecting that I would one day miss this.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, but on a separate note why are you using ngrok in production? You could just host this on a regular cloud hosting service, even serverless (e.g. Azure Function or AWS Lambda)

Comment: Hi Hilton, our chatbot is a company-internal chatbot that connects to a few internal databases/servers. Therefore it wasn’t practical to move it into the cloud (or I haven’t figured out a good implementation yet). However, the bot is hosted in a “secured” machine to prevent unauthorised connections.

Comment: Perhaps this is just my knowledge/experience with NGrok, but basically it's a developer tool - a command line app that you run as/when you want. By the same token if, for instance, the machine reboots, it will be shut down. Surely you want something more resilient, that will be up all the time (e.g. a Windows Service if on Windows)?

Comment: See for instance https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy#what-is-application-proxy or https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/how-to/preview-with-cloudflare-tunnel/